# why isn't my parsing from JSON working in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
with open('tweets.json') as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
        print(data['text'])
```

I want to extract specific data/values but I keep getting this error:

```
print(data['text'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I am a beginner with python and i am trying to learn by using the twitter api

this is my json:

```
"{\"created_at\":\"Wed Feb 03 03:02:04 +0000 2016\",\"id\":694717462621884416,\"id_str\":\"694717462621884416\",\"text\":\"Finallyy @taylorcaniff Happy bday bae, I love you soooo much, keep smiling, I'm so proud of everything you've done\\u2661 https:\\/\\/t.co\\/uwjeASxsA3\",\"source\":\"\\u003ca href=\\\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/download\\/android\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\"\\u003eTwitter for Android\\u003c\\/a\\u003e\",\"truncated\":false,\"in_reply_to_status_id\":null,\"in_reply_to_status_id_str\":null,\"in_reply_to_user_id\":null,\"in_reply_to_user_id_str\":null,\"in_reply_to_screen_name\":null,\"user\":{\"id\":1364125758,\"id_str\":\"1364125758\",\"name\":\"C o l l i n e r\",\"screen_name\":\"HoodsPizzaxJCat\",\"location\":\"2\\/5 UJ | The Vamps DM\",\"url\":null,\"description\":\"\\u25a8Issa liked x2 & follow\\u25a8Brent Follow, liked x4 &DM\\u25a8Chris liked x3 and follows\\u25a8Taylor, Kizzy, Jacob, Caspar, King B. & Momma Collins follow\\u25a8Trevor Liked \\u25a8\",\"protected\":false,\"verified\":false,\"followers_count\":12136,\"friends_count\":13282,\"listed_count\":20,\"favourites_count\":29245,\"statuses_count\":46864,\"created_at\":\"Fri Apr 19 10:59:10 +0000 2013\",\"utc_offset\":-10800,\"time_zone\":\"Buenos Aires\",\"geo_enabled\":true,\"lang\":\"es\",\"contributors_enabled\":false,\"is_translator\":false,\"profile_background_color\":\"09ED92\",\"profile_background_image_url\":\"http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_background_images\\/506799872326893569\\/vdaHWDTj.jpeg\",\"profile_background_image_url_https\":\"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_background_images\\/506799872326893569\\/vdaHWDTj.jpeg\",\"profile_background_tile\":true,\"profile_link_color\":\"4CC74C\",\"profile_sidebar_border_color\":\"FFFFFF\",\"profile_sidebar_fill_color\":\"DDEEF6\",\"profile_text_color\":\"333333\",\"profile_use_background_image\":true,\"profile_image_url\":\"http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/688994368057921536\\/IKy-2UYn_normal.jpg\",\"profile_image_url_https\":\"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/688994368057921536\\/IKy-2UYn_normal.jpg\",\"profile_banner_url\":\"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_banners\\/1364125758\\/1450566712\",\"default_profile\":false,\"default_profile_image\":false,\"following\":null,\"follow_request_sent\":null,\"notifications\":null},\"geo\":null,\"coordinates\":null,\"place\":null,\"contributors\":null,\"is_quote_status\":false,\"retweet_count\":0,\"favorite_count\":0,\"entities\":{\"hashtags\":[],\"urls\":[],\"user_mentions\":[{\"screen_name\":\"taylorcaniff\",\"name\":\"Taylor Caniff\",\"id\":1396698397,\"id_str\":\"1396698397\",\"indices\":[9,22]}],\"symbols\":[],\"media\":[{\"id\":694717457911693312,\"id_str\":\"694717457911693312\",\"indices\":[116,139],\"media_url\":\"http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/media\\/CaQh2OIWwAA6G_C.jpg\",\"media_url_https\":\"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/media\\/CaQh2OIWwAA6G_C.jpg\",\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/t.co\\/uwjeASxsA3\",\"display_url\":\"pic.twitter.com\\/uwjeASxsA3\",\"expanded_url\":\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/HoodsPizzaxJCat\\/status\\/694717462621884416\\/photo\\/1\",\"type\":\"photo\",\"sizes\":{\"large\":{\"w\":480,\"h\":800,\"resize\":\"fit\"},\"thumb\":{\"w\":150,\"h\":150,\"resize\":\"crop\"},\"small\":{\"w\":340,\"h\":566,\"resize\":\"fit\"},\"medium\":{\"w\":480,\"h\":800,\"resize\":\"fit\"}}}]},\"extended_entities\":{\"media\":[{\"id\":694717457911693312,\"id_str\":\"694717457911693312\",\"indices\":[116,139],\"media_url\":\"http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/media\\/CaQh2OIWwAA6G_C.jpg\",\"media_url_https\":\"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/media\\/CaQh2OIWwAA6G_C.jpg\",\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/t.co\\/uwjeASxsA3\",\"display_url\":\"pic.twitter.com\\/uwjeASxsA3\",\"expanded_url\":\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/HoodsPizzaxJCat\\/status\\/694717462621884416\\/photo\\/1\",\"type\":\"photo\",\"sizes\":{\"large\":{\"w\":480,\"h\":800,\"resize\":\"fit\"},\"thumb\":{\"w\":150,\"h\":150,\"resize\":\"crop\"},\"small\":{\"w\":340,\"h\":566,\"resize\":\"fit\"},\"medium\":{\"w\":480,\"h\":800,\"resize\":\"fit\"}}}]},\"favorited\":false,\"retweeted\":false,\"possibly_sensitive\":false,\"filter_level\":\"low\",\"lang\":\"en\",\"timestamp_ms\":\"1454468524972\"}\r\n"
```

Comment: Show what is inside the `tweets.json`?

Comment: seems that the `data` is a string not a dictionary

Comment: @d2207197 and how can i fix that? so i save my data as dictionary and not as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is in text format. (not in JSON). So first you have to convert it in JSON.

```
>>> json.loads(data)["text"]
u"Finallyy @taylorcaniff Happy bday bae, I love you soooo much, keep smiling, I'm so proud of everything you've done\u2661 https://t.co/uwjeASxsA3"
```

Comment: And how i can i do this for multiple lines? cause right now i just save one tweet json. But i want to fill the json with multiple tweet data and read them one by one is it possible do that?

Comment: In this case,you can take a data in list i.e. list of strings. You can iterate over the list and can find "text" for each sting.
for single in list_of_string:
   print json.loads(data)["text"]